# How to put many rollover images in the same page? non-js

Tags: html, image, rollover

This is my first post as a stackoverflow member.

Hi,
my question is how do I make many images that change when you pass your mouse over them?
I have a website for a small application that I have made and I have a page with download images for every version, and those images are the target.
I had tried two ways to make them rollover, and each way works fine until I put the images in the same page.  Then they don't work.

1st way

```
<a href='Destination URL' target="_top" onmouseover="document.sub_but.src='onrollimage'"onmouseout="document.sub_but.src='image'"><img src="image" width="281" height="55" name="sub_but"></a>
```

2nd way

```
<a href="Destination URL"  onmouseover= "if (document.images) document.bn_off.src= 'onrollimage';" onmouseout= "if (document.images) document.bn_off.src= 'image';"><img src="image" name="bn_off"></a>
```

if I use the same method twice it doesn't work, but if I put the first image the one way and the second image the other way it works fine.  I could leave it like this but in the feature I want to put more.
Please show me a way that I can put many image rollovers on the same page.

Check the specific page at http://www.torrentcleaner.tk/download.html
Also if you want check this http://www.torrentcleaner.tk/dimg/

Comment: Looks like javscript to me....

Comment: Yup. Everything in your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes is Javascript.

Comment: i didn't know this...however any answer for it?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't write this if you didn't even know you were writing javascript

Comment: when an article was saying that the code is in javascript, i couldn't understand anything that's why i wrote i didn't want js but my real question hasn't to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer is to change the code to

```
onmouseover= "this.children[0].src= 'onrollimage';"
```

and

```
onmouseout= "this.children[0].src= 'image';"
```

---

The correct way would be to use CSS ..

```
a.downloadButton{
    display:inline-block;
    height:55px;
    width:281px;
    background:url('path/to/image') top left no-repeat;

    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

a.downloadButton:hover{
    background-image:url('path/to/onrollimage');
}
```

and change your links to

```
<a href="Destination URL" class="downloadButton">download</a>
```

Comment: i just finished and it works fine (a little bit slow but it must be because of my hoster) Doesn't works in IE everything else is OK
thanks a lot, this is the way every site uses thanks again

Comment: @firstroad, if the elements are like your example, you can add to the rule the `zoom: 1;*display: inline;` to make it work in IE6 and IE7

Comment: i did this and i saw no change in ie9(that i have on my computer) but in google chrome it was showing no image

Comment: it doesn't work for me...but som,ething is wrong because in google chrome it doesn't show this code in the css and also i went to the link you gave me with ie and it shoew it me ok

Comment: something is really wrong, expression web has 'zoom' underlined and says: The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the current schema.

Comment: @firstroad, `zoom` css property is IE proprietary.. it is not a standard compliant property.. What i proposed with `zoom` and `*display` is an IE hack, to fix the specific problem.. not sure why it would not work for you though, as the example works.. might be conflicting with some other rule in your css ?